# The problems on sending email via phone gap iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, sendmail

According to [PhoneGap Email Composer Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069328/phonegap-email-composer-plugin). I have added `.m`, `.h`, `js` and framework in my project. But I don't know why, it has many warnings and errors.

**Warning:**

> /Users/mc228/project/platforms/ios/WorkplaceInspection/Plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer/APPEmailComposer.m:396:18: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

**Errors**

```
/Users/mc228/project/platforms/ios/EmailComposer.m:158:30: 'presentModalViewController:animated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0

/Users/mc228/project/platforms/ios/EmailComposer.m:162:19: 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

/Users/mc228/project/platforms/ios/EmailComposer.m:162:19: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'

/Users/mc228/project/platforms/ios/EmailComposer.m:190:17: 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

I also tried to use [Files doesn't support the ARC feature, how to deal with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633903/files-doesnt-support-the-arc-feature-how-to-deal-with) to solve, but it came out with more questions, such as:

1. `"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController"`, referenced from:
2. `"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController"`, referenced from:

All these questions come from `EmailComposer.m` file. Is there anyone helping me solve this problem?

Also, I didn't use objective C, I used HTML, CSS and JavaScript to build iOS application.

Comment: If you are using Cordova/PhoneGap >= 3.0 (released over a year ago), you should use the CLI to install plugins. https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer e.g. `cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer`

Comment: @LeeCrossley I applied cordova to install plugins. so i don't think that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have manually added files from an old version of the plugin as well as installing the latest version via `cordova plugin add`, there should not be a EmailComposer.m or EmailComposer.h:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/tree/master/src/ios

Delete any files you have added manually and any references you have added, the Cordova CLI handles this.

Comment: Yes, i did add EmailComposer.m EmailComposer.h manually. i will try again. thank u so much.

Comment: Thank u. i have solved plugin problem, but that code doesn't work, do you know how to write related code? is there some tutorials? i didn't  find it .

Comment: Examples here: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#examples if you need more help, probably best to ask the plugin author on github